# Error in Visual Studio while trying to add references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2015

Solved:

> I can't add references in Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop (C#),
>   I hope that it is the best version for me.
>            Anyway when trying to add references I get this following error:
>            [Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ccKg.png)
>            and after clicking "ok":
>            [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGdiR.png)
>            I did not see a lot of fixes on the internet, hope that I could get help here.

not solved:
P.S:

I have a warning in `app.config` :

> The 'configuration' element is not declared.

All those errors and warning appear in new projects and imported projects from Visual Studio 2013.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: perhaps you can start by showing what the app.config looks like

Comment: Sorry you are right, those he is showing this warning even when making new project.

Comment: For some reason renaming your (.sln) file has been the answer to others who had the same problem. Try rename your projects filename (.sln) extension to something else. And Restart your Visual Studio.

Comment: Your missing the <startup> tag in your app.config.

Comment: @Miguel no, that did not help, no effect at all :/.

Comment: @John Paul you are right, sorry I tryed to do some changing in it, but it is not the problem...

Comment: @Just Do It - i tryed all of them allready 1) I dont have dotNetConfig.xsd 2) Which "schemaURL"? 3 ) does not seems that he have a solution.

Comment: Poroblem solved after repair the visual studio! thanks for everyone! though i sill have the warning in app.config...